# Data fields in Data sources but not a field in JourneyBuilder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, data, marketing-cloud-connect

I have added a new object and data from Salesforce to Marketing cloud in data sources and it has synced. When I go to create a new journey, the object is there but not the fields. Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that this object is properly synchronised and all the fields you want, have been selected to be synchronised as well.

Navigate to **Contact Builder** > **Data Sources** > **Synchronised**.

If the object is set up properly and it doesn't show you any synch-errors, double check the Synchronised Data Extension in Email Studio.

Navigate to **Email Studio** > **Subscribers tab** > **Synchronised Data Extensions**.

Check if the object you're having this issue exists there and all the fields you have chosen are visible Data Extension attributes.

If these two are all correct and you are still not able to see your object under the `Contact Data` path, you may want to double-check that the object is correctly linked to Contact object (or directly linked to it)

Comment: Thank you!! I checked the first two steps and they are setup and showing. On the third step, it looks like the objects are not linked correctly.

Comment: Alright. However - do not start manually re-arranging Salesforce objects and their relations. Instead, create a new MC support case. Their backend team will resolve any issues with the SF object setup if needed.